# Is 100% black good in UI design?

Tags: color, interface-design, black

I was told that 100% black color makes eyes strain as it's too much contrast between white background and high color text. Ebooks, for example, does not use 100% black.

Are there any studies that show how people perceive different saturation of black on screens? Should I avoid 100% in UI design?

Comment: I've heard titles should never be 100% black.

Comment: Hi Peter. I edited your question merely to remove the word "rich". "Rich Black" and "100% Black" can mean two very different things to designers working in both print and screen design. If you feel my edit was unwarranted, you can click the *EDIT* link under your question and revise or rollback my edit.

Comment: This might come in handy: https://ianstormtaylor.com/design-tip-never-use-black/